# Existe metodo de inserção para arvore binária de busca mais rápido que o trivial?

Tags: c++, algoritmo, árvore-binária

Estou tentando resolver [este](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2120) problema em um judge online.

O problema fornece **N** inteiros que devem ser inseridos, na ordem dada, em um algoritmo de inserção de uma arvore binaria de busca. Depois **Q** consultas são realizadas. Para cada consulta o código deve dizer quem é o pai do elemento que é fornecido na entrada.

A entrada sera da seguinte forma:

> **N** (quantidade de valores)
>   N<sub>1</sub> N<sub>2</sub> ... N<sub>N</sub> (Sao os valores que devem ser inseridos na arvore)
>   **Q** (a quantidade de consultas)
>   Q<sub>1</sub> Q<sub>2</sub> ... Q<sub>Q</sub> (o inteiro que representa a posição do valor dado na entrada)

Para o seguinte exemplo de entrada seguindo a especificação acima:

> ```
> 5
> 3 1 4 2 5
> 2
> 2 5
> ```

O algoritmo deve formar a seguinte arvore:
[image: Arvore de busca]

E com essa arvore deve responder quem é o pai do segundo elemento dado na entrada (o pai de 1) e do 5 elemento da entrada (o pai de 5) separados por um espaço (não ha espaços apos o ultimo valor da saída)

Exemplo da saída esperada para a entrada do exemplo:

> ```
> 3 4
> ```

Para resolver esse problema usei o algoritmo trivial de inserção em arvores binarias (O que leva uma complexidade de pior caso de O(n<sup>2</sup>)). Durante a inserção, ja salvo o pai de cada nó em um mapa.

Mas, o código foi julgado como *tempo limite excedido*. Existe algum algoritmo de inserção mais rápido que o trivial (que mantenha a ordem dada na entrada ... arvores AVL vão alterar os pais de cada no...)?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unordered_map>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *leftChild;
    struct node *rightChild;
};

void insertAndBuildFather(node **tree, int data, std::unordered_map<int, int> &father){
    struct node *tempNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    tempNode->data = data;
    tempNode->leftChild = NULL;
    tempNode->rightChild = NULL;

    struct node *root = *tree;
    if(root == NULL){
        root = tempNode;
        father[root->data] = -1; //raiz nao tem pai
        *tree = root;
        return;
    }

    struct node *current = root;
    struct node *parent = NULL;

    while(1){
        parent = current;
        if(data < parent->data){
            current = current->leftChild;
            if(current == NULL){
                father[tempNode->data] = parent->data;
                parent->leftChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
        }
        else{
            current = current->rightChild;
            if(current == NULL){
                father[tempNode->data] = parent->data;
                parent->rightChild = tempNode;
                return;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main ( void ) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    struct node* tree = NULL;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> father; //guarda os pais de cada valor
    int in[n + 1];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &in[i]);
        insertAndBuildFather(&tree, in[i], father);
    }

    int q, qi;
    scanf("%d", &q);
    for (int i = 1; i < q; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &qi);
        printf("%d ", father[in[qi]]);
    }
    scanf("%d", &qi);
    printf("%d\n", father[in[qi]]);
}
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De modo geral, a inserção na BST é O(N) no pior caso (que é uma árvore pendendo completamente para um dos lados), o que realmente daria um algoritmo O(N²). No entanto, isso pode ser facilmente contornado mantendo-se onde está o maior nó da árvore e o menor nó da árvore. Caso o valor a ser inserido seja maior que o maior nó da árvore, então é só colocá-lo à direita do maior, e setá-lo como o novo maior, e fazer o mesmo para caso o valor a ser inserido seja menor que o menor. Desta forma, ao inserir um valor extremo, você reduz a complexidade de O(N) para O(1), recebendo Accepted.

Segue abaixo código exemplo AC:

```
// Gabriel Taets - Universidade Federal de Itajubá - gabrieltaets at gmail.com
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define F first
#define S second
#define mp make_pair
#define pb push_back
using namespace std;
typedef long long ll;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef pair<int,int> ii;
typedef vector<ii> vii;
int tree[200100];
int n, hi = -1, lo = 0x3f3f3f3f;
int matricula[100010];
int pai[100010];

void insere(int node){
  if(tree[0] == -1){
    hi = lo = node;
    tree[0] = tree[1] = node;
    return;
  }
  int atual = 0;
  if(matricula[node] > matricula[hi]){
    int dir = hi*2+1;
    tree[dir] = node;
    pai[node] = hi;
    hi = node;
    return;
  }
  if(matricula[node] < matricula[lo]){
    int esq = lo*2;
    tree[esq] = node;
    pai[node] = lo;
    lo = node;
    return;
  }
  while(1){
    int dir = atual*2+1, esq = atual*2;
    if(matricula[node] > matricula[atual]){
      if(tree[dir] == -1){
        tree[dir] = node;
        pai[node] = atual;
        return;
      }
      atual = tree[dir];
      continue;
    }
    else {
      if(tree[esq] == -1){
        tree[esq] = node;
        pai[node] = atual;
        return;
      }
      atual = tree[esq];
      continue;
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  scanf("%d",&n);
  memset(tree,-1,sizeof tree);
  for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    scanf("%d",&matricula[i]);
    insere(i);
  }
  int q;
  cin >> q;
  for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
    int x;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    if(i) putchar(' ');
    printf("%d",matricula[pai[x]]);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```

Uma boa dica também, geralmente é uma má ideia utilizar alocação dinâmica nesses problemas de Online Judges (a menos que você esteja treinando especificamente alocação dinâmica). Alocação Dinâmica é muito sensível a erros e pode causar crashes onde você nem imagina que pode estar errado no seu código. Portanto, se o seu objetivo com o Online Judge é treinar para competições de programação, recomendo que aprenda a representar árvores como vetores, como no código acima.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Nossa que estranho O.o ... Essa solução ainda é (N^2) ... nesses casos deveria ter mais informação sobre o problema T.T ... obrigado pela ajuda gabriel =D

Comment: Sim, ainda é N², mas os casos de testes são mal feitos o suficiente pra passar colocando só nas folhas os casos extremos :D